# How to map value from 1 table to another based on 2 column interval

Tags: r, sas

This question is how to map value from 1 table and assign value based on values from another table that its within the interval (2 columns).

The solution below is just for demonstration, the actual data is 1xx columns (for the object `b` and th. of rows of object `x` so current solution would require me to write down lots of lines of code (see object `w_aaa` and `w_bbb` etc.).

If R solution, preferably base R. Solution also in `SAS`.

```
# example data  
x <- data.frame(item_id=c(1,2,3),aaa=c(3,15,3),bbb=c(17,12,5),ccc=c(1,2,3))
p <- data.frame(bin=c(1:3,1:5),vmin=c(0,9,28,18.17,14.67,11.64,1.8,-0.33),
              vmax=c(8,27,40,35502,18,14.5,11.5,1.75),values=c(-0.62,-0.41,-0.04,-0.715,-0.46,-0.40,-0.14,0.27), 
              var=c(rep("aaa",3),rep("bbb",5))) 


# demonstrate simplified solution  
l <- with(p, split(p, var))
a <- x[ ,which(colnames(x) %in% as.character(l[[1]]$var[1])), drop=F]
b <- x[ ,which(colnames(x) %in% as.character(l[[2]]$var[1])), drop=F]

w_aaa <- apply(a, 1, function(x) l[[1]][ l[[1]]["vmin"] <= x & x <= l[[1]]["vmax"] ][4])
w_bbb <- apply(b, 1, function(x) l[[2]][ l[[2]]["vmin"] <= x & x <= l[[2]]["vmax"] ][4])

res <- data.frame(x,w_aaa,w_bbb)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SAS solution is to create an informat out of your P data set and then apply it using an array within a data step.

```
    *create an informat for your data;

    data p_formats;
        set p ;
        start=vmin;
    end=vmax;
    label=values;
    fmtname=var;
    type='I';
    run;

    proc format cntlin=p_formats;
    run;

    *apply informats using array to list of variables;
    *you can dynamically generate these lists if your variable list gets long;

    data want;
        set x;
        array _in(3) aaa bbb ccc;
        array _out(3) var_aa var_bb var_cc;

        do i=1 to dim(_in);
            _out(i)=inputn(_in(i), trim(vname(_in(i))));
        end;
    run;
```

I'm not proficient enough in R to offer an optimal solution but one that would work and scale would be to pivot_long your data to a long format and then merge the two tables and do the look up the same way you have it above.

EDIT: To handle missing or unfound values, add an 'Other' category, otherwise the default is to leave the value unchanged.

```
    data p_formats;
        set p end=eof ;
        start=vmin;
    end=vmax;
    label=values;
    fmtname=var;
    type='I';
    output;
    if eof then do;
      HLO='O'; *letter o;
      label = 'CHECKME';
      output;
    end;

    run;
```

Comment: Informat, of course! Completely forgot. I will check the solution but should be a good basis/demonstration for my purpose. Many thanks.

Comment: Many thanks for this solution, but the drawback is that when the value (`values`) is not found for the original value, the same value is assigned, how to put it as `missing` if not found?

Comment: Modified the answer, you need to add an `other` to account for the missing values, which PROC FORMAT does support, using the HLO option. See the edit in the answer above.

Answer (score 2):

In R, I prefer using `tidyverse`. I would go about it using wide-to-long transformation and doing the bulk of the work using Cartesian joins:

```
x %>% 
gather(var, val, -item_id) %>% #wide to long
left_join(p %>% mutate(var = as.character(var)), by = c("var" = "var")) %>% #cartesian join by "var"
filter(vmin <= val & val <= vmax) %>% 
mutate(var = paste0("w_", var)) %>%
select(item_id, var, values) %>% 
spread(var, values) %>% 
left_join(x, by = "item_id")
```